# How can I import(add) localSQL database to an existing AWS RDS with a similar table structure without replacing/removing AWS RDS contents

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a small local SQL database that I want to add/merge with the AWS RDS database (MY SQL). Both of them have similar table structures.

How can I merge the local SQL database with the existing AWS RDS with a similar table structure without replacing/removing AWS RDS contents?

Comment: In your RDS create another database and import data using DMS

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you refer me to a resource with detailed instructions?

Comment: Take a look at the official aws page https://aws.amazon.com/dms/

Comment: Yes, I've been looking at it. Though not found anything successfully till now. Thanks anyway.